# What does '|| {}' means

Tags: javascript

I stumbled with the following JavaScript code:

```
  var Employee = function (entity) {
        var employee = this;

        entity = entity || {};

        employee.employeeId = entity.EmployeeId;
        employee.email = entity.Email;
        employee.firstName = entity.FirstName;
        employee.lastName = entity.LastName; // ....
```

But I couldn't understand the following sentence:

```
 entity = entity || {};
```

Comment: if `entity` is `falsy` (null, undefined, 0.... ) assign to entity empty object `{}`

Comment: Assign to entity if truthy, otherwise assign to a new object.

Answer (score 2):

*||* is the OR statement in JavaScript. Your function receives *entity* as variable. When *entity* is null or undefined, your function will fill it up with empty object which is the same as *{}*.